# What is PBX in a Flash's default root password if you did an automated install?

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I'm stuck! The answer is somewhere out there on the web (I used to have it!) but I can't seem to find it now in my moment of need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, if using the ksauto the password is 'passworm'.